# How to export numbers from python then reuse them

Tags: python, numpy, export

I've got a function that integrates a pair of differential equations. Right now my code outputs a list for $c$ and a list for $\tau$. I'm plotting these the normal way. Now I want to do long calculations over a large time but the code takes a while so I would like to export some data that can later be called upon to plot figures quicker. How would I do this?
I have done a lot of research into pandas, and np.save but I don't fully understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to "export numbers from Python". You could write them to a `.txt` file, a `.json` file, or `.csv` file to name a few. I believe that since you mention `np.save()` that your data is currently in a `np.array()` format. If that is the case, then I would recommend that at the end of your processing script or function you simply call `np.save(outputfile.npz)`

documentation at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html?highlight=save#numpy.save

and then in your plotting script/function you can simply use `np.load(outputfile.npz)` at the top of your script to load it into Python for plotting

documentation at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html?highlight=load#numpy.load

I think this would be the easiest method to save and load numpy array to files on your computer, especially since it is built into the module!! However, for such a broad question this is essentially the extent to which the community can help you.